# How to avoid OptimisticLockException in unit test?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, optimistic-locking

I run a unit test with two test methods: one creates an entity on the H2 database, the other one finds it by some select criteria and deletes it afterwards. Both methods wrap all database interactions in JTA user transactions (one per method).

Now after some (unknown) changes in the backend, the delete method fails with an optimistic lock exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.OptimisticLockException: Newer version [null] of entity [[com.example.entities.MyEntity#10001]] found in database
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityVerifyVersionProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EntityVerifyVersionProcess.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:699)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireBeforeCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:532)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:235)
    ... 97 more
```

The entity has a `version` property which is annotated with `@Version`. The entities value is `0` and there isn't actually a newer version of that entity on the database. It looks like the finder works as expected (it finds the persisted entity)

Actually, the validator does not find a "current version". I was able to debug my way through the hibernate classes until I found the prepared statement that should *get* the current entity (in AbstractEntityPersister):

```
public Object getCurrentVersion(Serializable id, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {

    // ...   
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = session.getTransactionCoordinator()
                .getJdbcCoordinator()
                .getStatementPreparer()
                .prepareStatement( getVersionSelectString() );
        try {
            getIdentifierType().nullSafeSet( st, id, 1, session );
            ResultSet rs = session.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().getResultSetReturn().extract( st );
            try {
                if ( !rs.next() ) {
                    return null;  // <- that' where I end up. version = null
                }
```

The statement is correct, the id is correct too but the query result is empty.

```
prep68: select version from my_table where my_id =? {1: 10001}
```

But now the version number `0` is compared to `null`, they're not equal and that raises the OptimisticLockException.

Any help, tips, ideas and explanations are highly welcome.

Comment: If the result set row is null, then the db row for your entity has a null value in the version. This shouldn't happen if the schema was generated by Hibernate (@Version adds NOT NULL), but it might have happened somewhere in between schema updates or manual SQL queries.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - unfortunatly not, I double checked, added the very same query to the test method, inspected the entity and its version value is `0`. It looks to me, the entity isn't found by the persister at all...

Comment: Which would mean your entity isn't being persisted. Do you have a row in the DB for id `10001` (if that's the value for `my_id`)? Check that your unit test is correctly adding that entity to the DB and that it isn't rolling back (it does that unless you disable it (for junit that is (depending on TestRunner)) between method calls.

Comment: Yes. As I said, I added the very same prepared statement as a typed query to the "delete" test method and the result set had exactly one row, the one with id 10001 and version 0. And that's the irritating thing.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you have two unit tests? Are they: One that adds a row to the table and checks that that row is there; and one that deletes that row? If that's how your tests are set up, it might be that your test framework is rolling back the `insert` query. And so when you delete, it fails because there is nothing there. But that shouldn't give a version error. Can you put some test code in your question to clear up the context?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear this was a bug in Hibernate. When the transaction ends the entities being altered (with the `remove()` being one possible form of that) are fetched again to compare the database version number to that of the loaded entity and see if there's a difference. A difference implies the entity has been altered in the database during the transaction so it is aborted. Apparently, though, the entity would not be found exactly due to being removed. Of course at that point it's only removed in the entity manager, with the delete not yet being committed. I don't know whether that was the result of using the entity manager where it shouldn't be, or due to the deletes having been flushed and, although not committed yet, considered done within that transaction. In any case, the end result is comparing an actual version number with `null` and thus failing the lock test.

This has been fixed from Hibernate versions 4.3.8 and 5.0.0.Beta1 onwards. The issue can be found here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9419

This is an old question but it took one and a half year from it being asked to a fix being available. Most people are likely to be using newer Hibernate versions now (or using EclipseLink which at that point did exhibit correct behaviour), but there's a project where I'm forced to use an older version for legacy reasons and just got stung by this.